# How to generate country list with GWT from XML

Tags: gwt

I am looking for a way to get a list of Countries from this [ISO List of Countries](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm)

However I am not sure where to put the XML so the GWT RPC backend can read/parse the XML and generate the list.

Where to put the XML exactly, and how would the `ServiceImpl` will be able to read the file and do the parsing and generate a `List`.

Comment: So are you asking how to parse it, or where to put it?

Comment: Both, I mean I've read some post that the XML should be on the same level with the "index.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your needs.
If it is static resource you can just put to to classpath and load as

```
...getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/example/package/countries.xml")
```

If it is modifiable resource, you should put it to persistent (some RDBMS or other kind of storage), it even can be file if you strongly need it, but out of application, because next update you will need to manage modifications.

I wouldn't suggest to store that resource to web app root if you use it via RCP and don't need it as web resource. Because just one more resource and to get access you have to use some extra API, servlet context or other tricks in GWT part.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Locale Object.. you can get the list of ISO countries from it using`Locale.getISOCountries()` you can send them back to the client as a String array in an RPC call